No definition found for type AppDatabase using Room + Koin + KMP
I'm creating a proof of concept using KMP, I'm following this https://medium.com/@brilianadeputra/how-to-use-koin-and-room-database-in-kotlin-multiplatform-ce73577e4cc9 and this https://developer.android.com/kotlin/multiplatform/room docs to achieve my local database using Room + KMP + KOIN.
After some back and forth I got stucked with this error:
org.koin.core.error.NoDefinitionFoundException: No definition found for type 'net.makadu.poc09.AppDatabase'. Check your Modules configuration and add missing type and/or qualifier!

And here goes my code and my settings:
libs.versions.toml
[versions]
agp = "8.5.2"
kotlin = "2.0.21"
compose = "1.7.3"
compose-material3 = "1.3.0"
androidx-activityCompose = "1.9.3"

#customs
compose-plugin = "1.7.0"
koin = "4.0.0"
ktor = "3.0.0"
coroutines = "1.9.0"
json-serialization = "1.7.1"
room = "2.7.0-alpha10"
ksp = "2.0.21-1.0.25"
sqlite-bundled = "2.5.0-alpha10"


[libraries]
kotlin-test = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test", version.ref = "kotlin" }
androidx-activity-compose = { module = "androidx.activity:activity-compose", version.ref = "androidx-activityCompose" }
compose-ui = { module = "androidx.compose.ui:ui", version.ref = "compose" }
compose-ui-tooling = { module = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling", version.ref = "compose" }
compose-ui-tooling-preview = { module = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview", version.ref = "compose" }
compose-foundation = { module = "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation", version.ref = "compose" }
compose-material3 = { module = "androidx.compose.material3:material3", version.ref = "compose-material3" }

#customs
koin-core = { module = "io.insert-koin:koin-core", version.ref = "koin" }
koin-test = { module = "io.insert-koin:koin-test", version.ref = "koin" }
koin-compose = { module = "io.insert-koin:koin-compose", version.ref = "koin" }
koin-compose-viewmodel = { module = "io.insert-koin:koin-compose-viewmodel", version.ref = "koin" }

ktor-client-core = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-core", version.ref = "ktor" }

kotlinx-coroutines-core = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core", version.ref = "coroutines" }
kotlinx-coroutines-android = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android", version.ref = "coroutines" }

json-serialization = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json", version.ref = "json-serialization" }

room-gradle-plugin = { module="androidx.room:room-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "room" }
room-compiler = { module="androidx.room:room-compiler", version.ref = "room" }
room-runtime = { module="androidx.room:room-runtime", version.ref = "room" }
room-commom = { module="androidx.room:room-common", version.ref = "room" }
sqlite-bundled = { module="androidx.sqlite:sqlite-bundled", version.ref = "sqlite-bundled" }


#customs - android
koin-android = { module = "io.insert-koin:koin-android", version.ref = "koin" }
koin-androidx-compose = { module = "io.insert-koin:koin-androidx-compose", version.ref = "koin" }

ktor-client-okhttp = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp", version.ref = "ktor" }


#customs - ios
ktor-client-darwin = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin", version.ref = "ktor" }


#nothingtodo

[plugins]
androidApplication = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
androidLibrary = { id = "com.android.library", version.ref = "agp" }
kotlinAndroid = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
kotlinMultiplatform = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform", version.ref = "kotlin" }
kotlinCocoapods = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.cocoapods", version.ref = "kotlin" }
compose-compiler = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.compose", version.ref = "kotlin" }

#customs
jetbrainsCompose = { id = "org.jetbrains.compose", version.ref = "compose-plugin" }
ksp = { id = "com.google.devtools.ksp", version.ref = "ksp" }
room = { id = "androidx.room", version.ref = "room" }

sahred build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary)

    //customs
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsCompose)
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler)

    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "2.0.20"

    alias(libs.plugins.room)
    alias(libs.plugins.ksp)


}

kotlin {
    androidTarget {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "1.8"
            }
        }
    }
    
    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "shared"
            isStatic = true
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
            //put your multiplatform dependencies here

            implementation(compose.runtime)
            implementation(compose.foundation)
            implementation(compose.material)
            implementation(compose.ui)
            implementation(compose.components.resources)
            implementation(compose.components.uiToolingPreview)

            //compose
            implementation(libs.compose.foundation)
            implementation(libs.compose.ui)
            implementation(libs.compose.material3)
            //end compose

            //koin
            implementation(libs.koin.core)
            implementation(libs.koin.compose)
            implementation(libs.koin.compose.viewmodel)
            //end koin

            //ktor
            implementation(libs.ktor.client.core)
            //end ktor

            //coroutines
            implementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.core)
            //end coroutines

            //json serialization
            implementation(libs.json.serialization)
            //end json serialization

            //room
            implementation(libs.room.gradle.plugin)
            implementation(libs.room.runtime)
            implementation(libs.room.commom)

            implementation(libs.sqlite.bundled)

            //end room

            //implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-core-jvm:4.0.0")


        }
        commonTest.dependencies {
            implementation(libs.kotlin.test)
        }

        androidMain.dependencies {
            //koin
            implementation(libs.koin.android)
            implementation(libs.koin.androidx.compose)
            //end koin
            //ktor
            implementation(libs.ktor.client.okhttp)
            //end ktor

            //implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-android-scope:2.2.3")
        }
        iosMain.dependencies {
            //ktor
            implementation(libs.ktor.client.darwin)
            //end ktor

        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "net.makadu.poc09"
    compileSdk = 34
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 28
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

room {
    schemaDirectory("$projectDir/schemas")
}

shared Database.kt
package net.makadu.poc09

import androidx.room.ConstructedBy
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import androidx.room.RoomDatabaseConstructor
import androidx.sqlite.driver.bundled.BundledSQLiteDriver
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.IO
import net.makadu.poc09.repository.GeneralInfoEntity
import net.makadu.poc09.repository.database.GeneralInfoDao


@Database(entities = [GeneralInfoEntity::class], version = 1)
@ConstructedBy(AppDatabaseConstructor::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase(), DB {
    abstract fun getDao(): GeneralInfoDao

    override fun clearAllTables() { }

}

interface DB {
    fun clearAllTables(): Unit {}
}



@Suppress("NO_ACTUAL_FOR_EXPECT")
expect object AppDatabaseConstructor : RoomDatabaseConstructor<AppDatabase> {
    override fun initialize(): AppDatabase

}

fun getRoomDatabase(
    builder: RoomDatabase.Builder<AppDatabase>
): AppDatabase {
    return builder
        /*.addMigrations(MIGRATIONS)
        .fallbackToDestructiveMigrationOnDowngrade()*/
        .setDriver(BundledSQLiteDriver())
        .setQueryCoroutineContext(Dispatchers.IO)
        .build()
}

shared KoinDI.kt
package net.makadu.poc09.di



import net.makadu.poc09.GeneralInfoPresenter
import net.makadu.poc09.getRoomDatabase
import net.makadu.poc09.repository.local.GeneralInfoLocalRepository
import net.makadu.poc09.repository.local.IGeneralInfoLocalRepository
import org.koin.core.Koin
import org.koin.core.context.startKoin
import org.koin.dsl.KoinAppDeclaration
import org.koin.dsl.module


fun appModule() = module {

    single {


    }

    single<IGeneralInfoLocalRepository> { GeneralInfoLocalRepository(get()) }
    factory { GeneralInfoPresenter(get()) }
}

fun initKoin(appDeclaration: KoinAppDeclaration = {}) =
    startKoin {
        appDeclaration()
        modules(appModule())
    }

object KoinF {
    var di: Koin? = null

    fun setupKoin(appDeclaration: KoinAppDeclaration = {}) {
        if (di == null) {
            di = initKoin(appDeclaration).koin
        }
    }
}

androidapp folder Custom Application
package net.makadu.poc09.android

import android.app.Application
import android.content.Context
import net.makadu.poc09.di.KoinF
import org.koin.android.ext.koin.androidContext
import org.koin.core.component.KoinComponent


class MakaduApplication: Application(), KoinComponent {


    lateinit var context: Context

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        context = this

        KoinF.setupKoin {
            androidContext(this@MakaduApplication)
        }
    }

}

Full Error stacktrace: https://pastebin.com/kufZQWyh

What does your GeneralInfoPresenter look like? From looking at the stack trace you provided, koin is having problems creating an instance of GeneralInfoPresenter
